# Can you create a certificate from its thumbprint?

Tags: sql-server, certificate, ssl-certificate, database-restore, tde

its more of a concern than a problem. Here it goes;

I am trying to restore a [TDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) enabled SQL Server backup on a *separate* server.
While restoring I got an error this error

> Cannot find server certificate with thumbprint
>   0x210E6D33163FE11CSOMETHUMBPRINTIDONTWANTTOREVEAL

My concern : Is it a potential risk ? Can someone reverse engineer and create the certificate from its thumbprint?

Answer (score 3):

No. Thumbprint is a [one way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function). There is no way to create real certificate from thumbprint.

Answer (score -1):

**Backup the certificate with master key on the Primary Server**

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE  [EncryptionCertificate] 
TO FILE = 'Certificate File path'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'Master Key File path.dat', ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password')
```

**Restore the certificate with master key password on the Secondary Server**

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [EncryptionCertificate]
FROM FILE='Certificate File path'
WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE =  'Master Key File path.dat' , DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password')
```

This will resolve the issue and can restore the database with out any errors.

Comment: Thanks Raja but I am not looking for a solution. More of a concern than a problem. I know how to restore the certificate and then restore the database.

Comment: Downvote. Consider the situation when you dont have the certificate, but you want to create a fake certificate with the same thumbprint